# I want to code a banlist command with discord.py and change string to dictionary at this code

Tags: python, discord.py

Type of the ban_list variable is list. I changed its type to string for replace all = with : but i cant change string to dictionary.

```
@Bot.command()
async def banlist(ctx):
    ban_list = await ctx.guild.bans()
    ban_list = (str(ban_list))
    ban_list = (ban_list.replace("=",":"))
    ban_list1 = json.loads(ban_list)
    await ctx.send(ban_list1)
```

There is when ban_list's type is list:

```
[BanEntry(reason='Nothing.', user=<User id=*my id here name='*my username here' discriminator='6835' bot=False>)]
```

There is when i change all = to :

```
[BanEntry(reason:'Nothing.', user:<User id:*my id here name:'*my username here' discriminator:'6835' bot:False>)]
```

I want to dictionary look like that:

```
{'reason':'Nothing.', 'user':*my id here 'name':'*my username here' 'discriminator':'6835' 'bot':False}
```

Comment: You can't simply replace `=` with `:` to create a dictionary; `=` here is used to indicate keyword-arguments. Dictionaries are surrounded in `{}`, but you're trying to use `BanEntry` as a dictionary literal, which won't work. You might need to give more detail about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to make a banlist command that shows the information of all banned users

Comment: can you add what the dictionary should look like to the question?

Comment: @Guddi i add it to the question.is that possiple?if answer is no how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ban_list is a list containing all the bans, I think you're trying to convert each BanEntry into a list, the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20bans#discord.BanEntry) specify that `BanEntry` is a named tuple, to convert a namedtuple to a dictionary we can simply use the `_asdict` method.

```py
ban_list = await ctx.guild.bans()
dict_bans = [ ban._asdict() for ban in ban_list]
```

For getting user values,

```py
user = dict_bans[o].get('user') # a discord.User instance
print(user.name, user.discriminator)
```

### References:

- [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)
- [guild.bans](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20bans#discord.Guild.bans)

Comment: i use your code and try print(dict_bans) but it doesnt print dict_bans or an error

Comment: @Aslan @Ceres should be `ban._asdict()`

Comment: thank you it worked but how i can get name and discriminator's values? 
name = (dict_bans.get('name')) doesnt work.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me your discord? i have questions

Comment: Its in my profile [here](https://discord.com/users/488278979900342282)